# Data Binding giving NullPointerException when used with static method

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am getting a `NullPointerException` when I use to format date with my `StringUtils` class. If I use it without `StringUtils`, it just works fine.

I have added the import statement for `StringUtils`

I have this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@{StringUtils.getFormattedDate(user.date)}" />
```

This gives me an error in my `StringUtils` method:

```
public static String getFormattedDate(String unformattedDate) {
        // unformattedDate will be in format of yyyy-mm-dd
        // Convert it to d mmm, yyyy
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = null;
        try {
            Date d = df.parse(unformattedDate);   // <<--------- Here
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM, yyyy");
            date = dateFormat.format(d.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }
```

When I checked with debugger, `unformattedDate` is `null` from the beginning. The correct method is called but the value passed is `null`. This is strange.

When I use it like this in the layout file:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@{user.date}" />
```

It gives me no error, and date is displayed on screen!

I have tried cleaning the project and re-run it. But no success.

Comment: where and when you are setting value for `user`?

Comment: It is fetched async using firebase database. Is that causing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data bindings are null-safe itself, but this doesn't hold for using the values as parameter. Since the `getFormattedDate()` is yours to change, just make sure it's null-safe as well. You're already returning null if there's a `ParseException` anyway.

```
public static String getFormattedDate(String unformattedDate) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d = df.parse(unformattedDate);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM, yyyy");
        return dateFormat.format(d.getTime());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("StringUtils", "getFormattedDate", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more preferable i think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you run it for first time `user` is not having any value untill you get it from `Firebase` database, so `user.date` will also be null.

Put ternary :

```
android:text="@{user.date==null ? `` : StringUtils.getFormattedDate(user.date)}"
```

Comment: It is strange that it just doesn't give any specific error, and shows all my automatically generated binding classes are not found. I had this type of error when you put `android:text="@{user.amount}"` where amount is of type `double`. Putting `android:text="@{String.valueOf(user.amount)}"` compiles successfully. This is the case when you just don't get any specific error. I think Android Studio 2.1.3 still lakes when it comes to errors in data-binding